# Match against a cell and reference to a third one

Tags: excel, match

I have the following challenge.

I have a list with long names and a list with short names. Below example:

[image: example1]

Then I have raw data which has the long names. What I want is to match the long name from the raw data to the long name in the table and if it matches to provide me with the short name from the table.

[image: example2]

Answer (score 0):

Try an Index - Match:

```
=INDEX(short name range, MATCH(first cell in ''data that I have'',long name range,0))
```